# Dynamic number of tabs with firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, tabs

I have a group of category strings stored in `FirebaseFirestore.` Now, i want to show this list of strings with tabs using a `tabLayout.` This means that the number of tabs would be dynamic which would be set according to whats present on the database. For now, i know only how to show fixed number of tabs using this line of code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
```

So, how do i make the tabs dynamic such that the text and number of tabs are set from whats coming from the list of strings from my database? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that each tab is stored in a document in Firestore in a collection named `tabs`. You can then [get all documents in that collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) and create a tab with the ID of each document with:

```
db.collection("tabs")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(document.getId()));
                 }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```